# What are the technical differences between Debian and Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

What are the technical differences between Debian and Ubuntu for a modern server?

I know that Ubuntu has a lot more "polish" on the GUI, but this is not relevant to severs.

I know that some years ago Debian was hanging on to SysV init when Ubuntu wasn't, but now almost everyone has been assimilated into systemd.

I also know that it is more usual to have a root password on a Debian system and use `su` whereas Ubuntu heavily promotes the use of `sudo` and defaults to not permitting root login (but either approach is possible on either system).

I am not asking about the difference between the community or corporate guidance.

I know that Ubuntu releases more frequently and so supports newer hardware, but again this doesn't affect me much.  I am not interested in the release cycle of new features.  I would be using Ubuntu LTS or Debian stable.  I do care about timeliness of security updates.

**Edit:**

Ubuntu starts as a copy of Debian testing every 6 months, and then they make some changes.  **What changes are they?**  I am more interested in system-wide technical policy decisions, not package versions.  The sort of thing where one distro would consider something a bug and the other would mark it as a "won't fix".

Comment: You say what you don't care about, but apart from timeliness of security updates (I don't know where to get this information from), you don't say what you care about. Debian stable deploys MariaDB 10.3.27, Ubuntu 20.04 deploys 10.3.29. If that is the kind of information you are after, see packages.ubuntu.com and packages.debian.org. The two sites seem to have the same structure. Also, Ubuntu has its own installer and things like MAAS and Juju, is the native platform for LXD  and has its own OpenStack deployers. Debian is notoriously peculiar about open-source, Ubuntu not so much.

Comment: what's the use case/business problem that made you have to choose between both distros?

Comment: See edit. My personal use case is a low traffic web and mail server, probably running lighttpd and postfix.

Comment: Re “Ubuntu starts as a copy of Debian testing every 6 months”, that’s a common misconception; see [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404258/86440) for a description of what really happens.